# Javascript RegEx: Matching indented comments

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently trying to parse out comments in a particular format using JavaScript. While I have a basic understanding of regular expressions, with this one I seem to have reached my current limit. This is what I am trying to do:

The comments

```
//
    This is a
    multiline comment

Code here


//
    This is another
    comment

Again, code here
```

For the Regex, it currently looks this like this:

```
\/\/\n(\s+[\s\S]+)
```

- `\/\/\n` matches the `//`sequence including the new line.
- Since I am interested in the comments, I am opening a capture group.
- `\s+` matches the indentation. I could probably be a bit more precise by only accepting tabs or spaces in a particular count – for me this is not relevant
- `[\s\S]` is supposed to match the actual words and and spaces between the words.

This seems to currently match the whole file, which is not what I want. What I now can't wrap my head around is how to solve this?

I think my problem is related to me not knowing how to think about regexes. Is it like a program that matches line per line, so I need to work more on the quantifiers? Or is there maybe a way to stop at lines only consisting of a newline? When I try to match for the newline character, I of course receive matches at each line ending, which is not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/^\/\/((?:\r?\n[^\S\r\n].*)*)/gm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m1beWQ/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line (due to `m` modifier, `^` also matches line start positions)
- `\/\/` - a `//` string
- `((?:\r?\n[^\S\r\n].*)*)` - Capturing group 1: zero or more repetitions of

  - `\r?\n` - a CRLF or LF line ending
  - `[^\S\r\n]` - any whitespace but CR and LF
  - `.*` - the rest of the line.

JS demo:

```js
var text = "//\n    This is a\n    multiline comment\n\nCode here\n\n\n//\n    This is another\n    comment\n\nAgain, code here";
var regex = /^\/\/((?:\r?\n[^\S\r\n].*)*)/gm, m, results=[];
while (m = regex.exec(text)) {
  results.push(m[1].trim());
}
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thank you! With your answer I was able to understand RegExes A LOT better than before. It's like magic once you get the hang of it!